# How to match exact type on discriminated union on Typescript

Tags: typescript, discriminated-union

I want to check for exact types on a discriminated union as follows:

```
interface Circle {
  kind: "circle";
  radius: number;
}

interface CircleCustom {
  kind: "circle";
  radius: number;
  customProp1: number;
  customProp2: number;
}

interface Square {
  kind: "square";
  sideLength: number;
}

type Shape = Circle | CircleCustom | Square;

let myCustomCircle: Shape = {
  kind: 'circle',
  radius: 1,
  customProp1: 1,
  // missing customProp2, no error is trigered
}
```

I need the compiler to understand that when the `customProp1` is there then the `customProp2` must be available as well.

Is there another way to achieve this?

Comment: ALso, you can check my article where you can find several useful type utilities for unions

Comment: Article is [here](https://catchts.com/unions)